# Cells are missing in ADO query

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I am querying three workbooks, each with three sheets, and collating them into a single workbook with the three collated sheets.

It runs; however, every-so-often, there are missing cells.

I did some research and some say it happens when you use an older connection string. I am not.
Others say it happens when the char length exceeds 255. The missing cells are either length 6 of integers or length 8 of double.
Others say it happens when the query has more than 65,535 rows of data. Each of my queries have at most 3,000 rows.

I have a duplicate column of the same data in the original sheets and the duplicate is missing different rows than the first column.

Of the 6000 rows total rows in each resulting sheet, only 26 sporadic cells are blank in the main column of the first sheet; none are missing from the duplicate column.
No cells are missing from the main column of the second sheet, however the duplicate column has big chunks of cells missing totaling around 500 cells.
The third sheet is unfazed.

As a workaround, I run a loop checking for blank cells and copying it from the other column.

Is there a way to get all the data to appear in the queries?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub report_SourceDataFile()
    Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim strConn As String, strQuery As String, strPath As String
    Dim shtArr As Variant, shtElm As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow As Long

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Add
    shtArr = Array("sht1", "sht2", "sht3")

    For i = 2018 To 2020
        strPath = "path" & i & ".xlsm"
        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
        connection.Open strConn

        For Each shtElm In shtArr
            wbSource.Sheets.Add(after:=wbSource.Sheets(wbSource.Sheets.Count)).Name = shtElm
            strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & shtElm & "$]"
            rs.Open strQuery, connection

            ' Write header
            If i = 2018 Then
                For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                    wbSource.Sheets(shtElm).Cells(1, j + 1).Value = rs.Fields(j).Name
                Next j
            End If

            lastrow = wbSource.Sheets(shtElm).Cells(wbSource.Sheets(shtElm).Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            wbSource.Sheets(shtElm).Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
            rs.Close
        Next shtElm

        connection.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the missing cells always the same ones? Missing cells can sometimes be due to the query provider having decided a column is of a certain datatype (typically having looked at the first x number of rows), and then later values in the column are of a different type, and end up as nulls.  Could that be the case here?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your response. It is the same cells every time I run the sub. There is no difference between the cells concerning datatype. The entire column is set as number and from start to end, the value is an incremental reference number for the first sheet. The second sheet is also a reference number, but it is not incremental, also no differences in datatype. There are minus signs and decimals in this sheet, however the main column, all show up with no issues.

Comment: Are you able to share a workbook with data which can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, I can share a scrubbed file which I have confirmed duplicates the issue; however, I can only email it. I am on a secure network and file hosting sites are blocked.

Comment: @TimWilliams it has been sent!

Comment: The code has `shtArr = Array("sht1", "sht2", "sht3")` but there isn't any code that changes the names of the sheets in `wbSource` to match the names in `shtArr`

Comment: @barrowc apologies. It was removed during my scrubbing of unnecessary code of the issue. I added it back.

Comment: For anyone following - looks like the source files have occasional cells with "number stored as text": this was causing them to show up as nulls in the recordset.  By default the provider only scans the first 8 rows of the data to determine the datatype of each column, and any subsequent values which do not match that datatype are dropped and become nulls in the recordset.